# How to set an MS-Access textbox to intuit what you're typing based on table values?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there a way to program a textbox in Access to intuit - or guess - what the user is trying to type like the Google search bar does? The intuition would come from existing table values as a method to prevent duplication of data - especially in circumstances where the date is in short text format and a small spelling error could create a duplicate.

Comment: Use combo boxes with recordsources which does auto find/complete.

Comment: This is what a combobox does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take an idea of combobox with Google-like search-as-you-type feature with context search from [here](http://e-e.com/A_6490.html). The article contains working database example.

Comment: I'd say this is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: The link I gave has not only description of idea, but also ready to use database example with class. I slightly modified this class and using it in most of my applications, so it's complete answer. My class contains about 600 rows, I don't think it's reasonable to publish it here.

Comment: Based on everyone's comments I understand now how a combo box can be used to avoid duplicates. Thank you